# Parse JSON stored in table column in Python Spark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to parse JSON and add a column to a DataFrame using Python Spark:

```
tableDF = spark.sql("select  * from transaction")

stats_df = parseJSONCols(tableDF)

def parseJSONCols(df):
    res = df
    cols = ['State']

    for i in cols:
        schema = spark.read
            .json(res.rdd.map(lambda x: x[i]))
            .schema
        res = res.withColumn("selectedState", lit(filterSelectedState(col(i))))

    return res
```

where `State` is a JSON string with this structure:

```
[
    {
        isSelected: true,
        name: 'x'
    },
    {
        isSelected: false,
        name: 'y'
    }
]
```

I want to extract the value of the `isSelected` field and add that in a `selected` column in `tableDF`.

Can someone please help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
df = df.withColumn('isSelected', f.col('State').getItem('isSelected'))
```

However, it would be useful to see the output of  say `stats_df.take(2)` so that we can see the exact structure of DF you are dealing with.